# substring variable name python

Tags: python, variables, eval

i have few variables like this:

```
self.lamp_1
self.lamp_2
self.lamp_3
self.lamp_4
```

and now i want to use each of this names is loop to call them automaticly, like this:

```
for i in range(1,5):
    self.canvas.itemconfig(self.lamp_/number_i_automaticly/, fill=self.color_blink)
```

I tried using function eval() but it doesn't work. It stops running my program.

```
eval("self.canvas.itemconfig(self.lamp_"+str(i)+",fill=self.color_blink)")
```

how can i declerate names of variables in that way, using key i?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* use [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr) for this:

```
for i in range(1,5):
    self.canvas.itemconfig(getattr(self, 'lamp_%s' % i),
                           fill=self.color_blink)
```

But you really shouldn't name your variables like this. Put them in a list and iterate over that:

```
self.lamps = [self.lamp_1, self.lamp_2, self.lamp_3, self.lamp_4]
for lamp in self.lamps:
    self.canvas.itemconfig(lamp, fill=self.color_blink)
```

Comment: i used this:
`self.canvas.itemconfig(eval("self.lamp_{0}".format(i)), 
                                   fill=self.color_blink)`
and it works fine! thanks a lot!!

Comment: @greg: It's a very bad idea to use indexed variable names.  It's an even worse idea to use `eval()` instead of `getattr()` to access them.  Do yourself a favour by not ignoring our advice! :)

Answer (score 8):

Use a list instead of indexed variable names:

```
self.lamps = [lamp_1, lamp_2, lamp_3, lamp_4]
```

If you insist on using indexed variable names (you shouldn't), you can use `getattr()`:

```
for i in range(1, 5):
    self.canvas.itemconfig(getattr(self, "lamp_%i" % i), 
                           fill=self.color_blink)
```

Comment: getattr() doesn't work properly. it's says that's something wrong with arguments. what could that be?

Comment: @greg: How am I supposed to know?  You neither told me what you tried nor what error message you got. :)

Comment: i find out what the problem was. this is for version 2.7 and I'm using 3.2, it works fine. thanks and sorry for weak comment.

Comment: @greg: There's no difference in the usage of `getattr()` between 2.7 and 3.2.  The above code should work in both versions.

Comment: i don't know what was the problem than, i copy your version and there was and error. important is that we solved the problem ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try to avoid using eval whenever possible. In this case you could use `getattr`:

```
for i in range(1, 5):
    value = getattr(self, 'lamp_%d' % i)
```

But I agree: you should be using a list (or a dictionary) instead.

Edit: oh, and use `setattr` to set them:

```
setattr(self, 'lamp_%d' % i, value)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest doing this as @SvenMarnach suggests. However, if you **must** use for some *external* reason `lamp_1` etc, you should change your loop from `range()` to:

```
for lamp in (self.lamp_1, self.lamp_2, self.lamp_3, self.lamp_4):
    self.canvas.itemconfig(lamp, fill=self.color_blink)
```